# Flow not emitting items

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The code below implements a simple screen that shows a list of users using the MVI pattern with kotlin coroutines. The code runs but does not produce any results. After alot debugging, i found out that the **getUsers** function in the **UserListVM** does not emit anything. Would appreciate some help here. thanks alot.

```
    class UserListVM : ViewModel() {

    val resultFlows: Channel<Flow<*>> = Channel(Channel.UNLIMITED)
    val liveState = MutableLiveData<PModel<*, UserListIntents>>()
    val intents: Channel<UserListIntents> = Channel()

    lateinit var job: Job
    lateinit var currentState: UserListState

    fun offer(event: UserListIntents) = intents.offer(event)

    suspend fun store(initialState: UserListState): LiveData<PModel<*, UserListIntents>> {
        job = viewModelScope.launch {
            currentState = initialState
            intents.consumeEach { intent ->
                resultFlows.send(reduceIntentsToResults(intent, currentState)
                        .flowOn(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4).asCoroutineDispatcher())
                        .map { SuccessResult(it, intent) }
                        .catch { ErrorEffectResult(it, intent) }
                        .onStart { emit(LoadingEffectResult(intent)) }
                        .distinctUntilChanged()
                )
            }
            resultFlows.consumeEach { results ->
                results.flatMapMerge {
                    val states = stateStream(this as Flow<Result<UserListResult, UserListIntents>>, currentState)
                    val effects = effectStream(this as Flow<Result<UserListEffect, UserListIntents>>)
                    flowOf(states, effects)
                }
                        .flattenMerge()
                        .collect { pModel -> liveState.value = pModel }
            }
        }
        job.start()
        return liveState
    }

    private suspend fun reduceIntentsToResults(intent: UserListIntents, currentState: Any): Flow<*> {
        Log.d("UserListVM", "currentStateBundle: $currentState")
        return when (intent) {
            is GetPaginatedUsersIntent -> when (currentState) {
                is EmptyState, is GetState -> getUsers()
                else -> throwIllegalStateException(intent)
            }
            is UserClickedIntent -> when (currentState) {
                is GetState -> flowOf((SuccessEffectResult(NavigateTo(intent.user), intent)))
                else -> throwIllegalStateException(intent)
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun getUsers(): Flow<UsersResult> {
        return flow {
            emit(UsersResult(listOf(User("user1", 1), User("user2", 2), User("user3", 3))))
        }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        job.cancel()
    }
    }

    class UserListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var intentStream: Flow<UserListIntents> = flowOf()
    lateinit var viewModel: UserListVM
    lateinit var viewState: UserListState
    private lateinit var usersAdapter: GenericRecyclerViewAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        initialize()
        setupUI(savedInstanceState == null)
        viewModel.store(viewState).observe(this, Observer {
            it?.apply {
                when (this) {
                    is ErrorEffect -> bindError(errorMessage, error, intent)
                    is SuccessEffect -> bindEffect(bundle as UserListEffect)
                    is SuccessState -> {
                        (bundle as UserListState).also { state ->
                            viewState = state
                            bindState(state)
                        }
                    }
                }
                toggleLoadingViews(intent)
            }
        })
    }

    fun initialize() {
        viewModel = getViewModel()
        viewState = EmptyState()
    }

    fun setupUI(isNew: Boolean) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_list)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        toolbar.title = title
        setupRecyclerView()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (viewState is EmptyState) {
            GlobalScope.launch {
                viewModel.offer(GetPaginatedUsersIntent(0))
            }
        }
    }

    private fun bindState(successState: UserListState) {
        usersAdapter.setDataList(successState.list, successState.callback)
    }

    private fun bindEffect(effectBundle: UserListEffect) {
        when (effectBundle) {
            is NavigateTo -> {
               // ..
            }
        }
    }

    fun bindError(errorMessage: String, cause: Throwable, intent: UserListIntents) {
        //..
    }

    private fun setupRecyclerView() {
        usersAdapter = object : GenericRecyclerViewAdapter() {
            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): GenericViewHolder<*> {
                return when (viewType) {
                    R.layout.empty_view -> EmptyViewHolder(layoutInflater
                            .inflate(R.layout.empty_view, parent, false))
                    R.layout.user_item_layout -> UserViewHolder(layoutInflater
                            .inflate(R.layout.user_item_layout, parent, false))
                    else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Could not find view of type $viewType")
                }
            }
        }
        usersAdapter.setAreItemsClickable(true)
        user_list.layoutManager = androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager(this)
        user_list.adapter = usersAdapter
        usersAdapter.setAllowSelection(true)
        intentStream = flowOf(intentStream, user_list.scrollEvents()
                .map { recyclerViewScrollEvent ->
                    GetPaginatedUsersIntent(
                            if (ScrollEventCalculator.isAtScrollEnd(recyclerViewScrollEvent))
                                viewState.lastId
                            else -1)
                }
                .filter { it.lastId != -1L }
                .conflate()
                .onEach { Log.d("NextPageIntent", "fired!") })
                .flattenMerge()
    }

    fun toggleLoadingViews(isLoading: Boolean, intent: UserListIntents?) {
        linear_layout_loader.bringToFront()
        linear_layout_loader.visibility = if (isLoading) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
    }
```

Comment: Is it even properly called? Had basic use of corutines, but shouldn't you call suspended fun by scope.launch { getUsers() } to be properly called?

Comment: I am still trying to wrap my head around flows and channels. So how do you suggest calling it properly ?

Comment: _Suspend function 'callGetApi' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function_
I was wrong about call.
Maybe try to change 

return flow {
            emit(UsersResult(listOf(User("user1", 1), User("user2", 2), User("user3", 3))))
        }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)

with 

return flowOf(UsersResult(listOf(User("user1", 1), User("user2", 2), User("user3", 3))).flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)

Comment: I think that's because you are not calling a terminal operator on `getUsers()` since flows are cold observables.

Comment: @MilanKundacina I applied your suggestion but still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is `intents.consumeEach` is waiting for `intents` to be closed but it is never closed. Which means `resultFlows.consumeEach` is never reached, so it might look like `getUsers` is not emitting anything but it's actually not being consumed.

Quick fix would be to wrap each `consumeEach` in a `launch`, but I recommend a refactor/re-design.

Side note: Functions that return `Flow` shouldn't suspend.

Comment: May I know why function that returns `Flow` should not suspend? Can you also provide some good source pertaining to it? Thank you

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS `Flow` is lazy and `suspend` is eager. Having a function eagerly returning a lazy primitive is silly to reason about. Either you return a lazy primitive or you return the final value. Using both does not make sense.

Comment: Thanks, but it is okay to call suspend function inside a `flow` is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's how you are expected to use `flow`.

Answer (score 0):

In my specific case, `distinctUntilChanged` was the reason why some of the values weren't being received